# Is there a way to automatically train Wit.ai?

Tags: wit.ai

I know Wit.ai engine can be trained by manually validate cases, but is there a way to train it with a set of defined inputs and outputs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can probably look at the export format of one of your app and tweak it to import in a new app. https://wit.ai/docs/recipes#manage-link

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [wat.ai API](https://wit.ai/docs/http/20160526) to create an `intent` entity:

```
curl -X "POST" "https://api.wit.ai/entities" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer [token]" \
    -d "{\"id\":\"intent\",\"doc\":\"Describe the users overall intention\",\"lookups\":[\"trait\"]}"
```

and then train it with values:

```
curl -X "POST" "https://api.wit.ai/entities/intent/values" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer [token]" \
    -d $'{
      "value": "hello",
      "expressions": [
        "hi",
        "hello",
        "oi",
        "bonjour",
        "aloha"
      ]
    }
```